# Fatal error : invalid -march= option: 'armv5t'

Tags: embedded-linux, stm32, fatal-error, u-boot

I'm following [bootlin lab](https://bootlin.com/doc/training/embedded-linux-4d/embedded-linux-4d-labs.pdf) to make a linux image that could be flashed on stm32mp157 discovery board.
Now, I'm trying to make u-Boot.
I have downloaded it from [here](https://gitlab.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot.git) and configure it through menuconfig as the lab has mention it.
When I launch the make command under u-boot folder , I got this error :
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the actual configuration file that was generated by `make menuconfig` (in text format, please) ?